# PHP urlencoded variable becomes undefined?

Tags: javascript, php, urlencode

I have a html page with some buttons, one of my buttons is as following:

```
<input class="contentLink" type="button" value="Questionnaire" onclick="validate(<?php urlencode('/my-site/Tools/Learning_Strategies/Questionnaire.php'); ?>)"/>
```

Essentially when this button is clicked, it passes the urlencoded-string literal '/my-site/Tools/Learning_Strategies/Questionnaire.php' into the javascript method validate:

```
function validate(url){
    alert(url);
    location.href="/my-site/Session/redirectMe.php?loc="+url;
}
```

What I am trying to do is get '/my-site/Session/Questionnaire.php' from the html page accessible from the redirectMe.php. This is being setup in the

```
location.href="/my-site/Session/redirectMe.php?loc="+url;
```

which leads to my redirectMe.php file:

```
<?php
require "SessionAuthenticator.php";
Session_start();
if(validateSession()===true){//validateSession() is defined inside SessionAuthenticator.php
    echo $_GET["loc"];
    //header("Location: ".$_GET["loc"]);
}else{
    header("Location: /my-site/LoginPage/index.php");
}
?>
```

The issue is during both of the alert and echo, the encoded string literal came out as "undefined", which means the following line:

```
header("Location: ".$_GET["loc"]);
```

will really look like this:

```
header("Location: undefined");
```

And therefore look for 'undefined' in the current directory and break the website.

This all works perfectly if there is no encoding as following:

```
<input class="contentLink" type="button" value="Questionnaire" onclick="validate('/my-site/Tools/Learning_Strategies/Questionnaire.php')"/>
```

But... No encoding is bad right?

If you are wondering why you don't see a decode method being used...

> The webserver will arrange for $_GET to have been urldecoded once already by the time it reaches you! - Matt Johnson ¶ @ http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php#48481

Require and include will not work, as redirectMe.php would be executed before the user even sees the page. This should only happen when the user clicks the button. That is why I am using a javascript function to start redirectMe.php.

I've tried ajax, however this didn't work. After talking with an experienced programmer who I know personally, I've been told that ajax can't help me here. This because Ajax would be redirected to '/my-site/Tools/Learning_Strategies/Questionnaire.php', but not the client (User).

To clearly state my question:

Why is the urlencoded coming up as 'undefined' when echo-ed/alert-ed? How do I fix this?

As for programs/web servers/etc I am using...

Sublime 3 (text editor)

Wamp (64BIT)(all-in-one package) @ http://www.wampserver.com/en/

Apache 2.4.17

PHP 7

MySQL 5.7.9

I am open to other means of getting what I am trying to do done.

However, I am not open to changing web servers/programs etc (except sublime 3 since it is just a text editor.... but why would that need to be required?).

Furthermore, whatever means of getting this done needs to support the browsers/platforms as stated below.

The website must support:

(Browsers)

IE 8 and up, and latest versions of Microsoft Edge, Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

Cross-Platform:

Windows 7 and up, and the latest versions of Mac OS, IOS and Android

Answer (score 3):

> Why is the urlencoded coming up as 'undefined' when echo-ed/alert-ed?

Because the PHP doesn't output anything.

> ```
> <input class="contentLink" type="button" value="Questionnaire" onclick="validate(<?php urlencode('/my-site/Tools/Learning_Strategies/Questionnaire.php'); ?>)"/>
> ```

Gives you:

```
<input class="contentLink" type="button" value="Questionnaire" onclick="validate()"/>
```

… once you run it through a PHP parser.

You need to:

- `echo` the result so something appears there
- wrap it in quotes (with `json_encode` so any escaping needed is also taken care of) so that it will be treated as a string and not a variable name.

Comment: can you provide an example with json_encode? I'm getting "Unexpected token }" in the chrome developer tool with    onclick="validate(<?php echo json_encode(urlencode('/my-site/Tools/Learning_Strategies/Questionnaire.php'));?>)"

Comment: @Tyler - That PHP is correct. I don't see any `}` in it and I can't see anywhere a `}` in any of the code in the question would throw that error. The developer tools will give you a line number that the error occurred on. Click on it.

Comment: The developer is pointing at the input tag with that onclick code. It also seems weird to me as there isn't even any } in the php file (html page), and with a lot of echo-testing, there isn't any } in the url, before and after encoding... Well putting this aside; after speaking with some more people elsewhere, I found out that I don't need to encode the url because I have complete control over the url. There is no user-input influencing it, or anything. Simplifying the button - you click it, and you go to another page.